# What do I do with a P11D Expenses & Benefits form?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom

The form is from HM Revenue & Customs and it seems to outline items that my previous company paid for (travel, in my case).

The very first thing the letter says is

**`For your records only. Do not send to HM Revenue & Customs.`**

Under `Class 1A Items`, the **`Other Class 1A Items`** is ticked.

In the summary, it says **`Cost to you: £576.55`**

Am I required to do anything? What am I paying for and how do I know it is accurate?

I am currently employed elsewhere, if it matters.

Comment: See [Wiki Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P11D). It's a copy of expenses your old company reported to HMR&C. It would appear you don't need to do anything (unless, perhaps, you need to complete Self Assessment).

Comment: I am still unclear on the amount at hand - what does it mean? Do I owe this much in taxes? How does it get deducted, etc...?

Comment: @Petar It’s accounted for in your PAYE code, so your employer will be deducting the correct amount of tax from your salary every month. There’s nothing that you need to do. If you have to do a tax return, then you’ll need the information for your tax return.

Comment: @mikescott you should make that an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The P11D is a record of the total benefits you've received in a tax year that haven't been taxed in another way, a bit like the P60 is a record of the total pay and tax you've paid in a tax year.

Note that travel for business purposes shouldn't be taxable, and if that's what's being reported on the P11D you may need to make a claim for tax relief to HMRC to avoid having to pay the tax. I'm not sure whether it's normal for such expenses to be reported there.

HMRC will normally collect that tax by adjusting your tax code after the P11D is issued, so that more tax is taken off your future income. So you don't need to do anything, as it'll be handled automatically.

As to how you know it's accurate, if you have any doubts you'd need to contact your former employer and ask them to confirm the details. In general you ought to know what benefits you actually received so should at least be able to figure out if the number is plausible. If your "travel" was a flight to the USA, then probably it was. If it was a bus ticket, less so :-)

If you fill in a tax return, you'll also have to report the amount there which will increase the tax you owe/reduce your refund. You won't be charged twice even if your tax code also changes, as the tax return accounts for the total amount of tax you've already paid.

For travel benefits, the exact treatment in relation to tax/P11Ds is summarised [here](https://www.gov.uk/expenses-and-benefits-travel/what-to-report-and-pay).